# When I go between if I go between 3 and 10, its marked as greater than 20

Tags: javascript, html

If the the element Wager is set to anything above 3 and under 10. Javascript marks it as above 20.

```html
<input type="number" id="wager" step="0.1" min="0.1" max="20.0" placeholder="0.1"/>
```

```js
function setTwoNumberDecimal(event) {
    this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(1); 

    console.log(this.value) // Shows the current value (debugging)
    console.log(this.max) // Shows the max value allowed (debugging)
    console.log(this.value > this.max) // Shows if its above the max allowed (debugging)

    if (this.value > this.max) {
        this.value = this.max
    }

    if (this.value < 0.1) {
        this.value = 0.1
    }
}
```

I was expecting so anything between 3 and 10 would be marked as lower than 20 but yeh. It probably is something stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is a result of comparing strings. First, `this.value` and `this.max` return strings from the HTML element, even after being assigned a number value. Second, the method `toFixed()` also returns a string. Instead we'll apply it after comparing values.

```js
function setTwoNumberDecimal(event) {
  var _thisValue = parseFloat(this.value);
  var _thisMin = parseFloat(this.min);
  var _thisMax = parseFloat(this.max);

  if (_thisValue > _thisMax) {
    this.value = _thisMax.toFixed(1);
  } else if (_thisValue < _thisMin) {
    this.value = _thisMin.toFixed(1);
  } else {
    this.value = _thisValue.toFixed(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: The parseFloat() is doing another function. I want the input to always have a decimal place in the tenth place. Also thank you very much

Comment: That makes sense. My head was in the right place for efficiency, as you'd have to use `parseFloat` a second time for each `var` after applying `toFixed`, but it's actually much better to just compare values while they're numbers before `toFixed` turns them into strings

Comment: Actually I have just tested what you explained. And im getting the same issue. Any number 3 and above until 10 gets marked as being above the max.

```
        this.value = parseInt(this.value)//.toFixed(1); 
        this.max = parseInt(this.max)

        console.log(this.value)
        console.log(this.max)
        console.log(this.value > this.max)
```

Comment: I have discovered the issue is not within the parsing itself since if i remove the first 2 lines setting `this.max` and `this.value` everything is still broken

Comment: You're still comparing `this.value` and `this.max` which will always return strings from an HTML element. That is why I used `var _thisValue` `var_thisMin` and `var _thisMax` to store them as numbers.